# Design Pattern for Creating Sql Queries

Tags: sql, t-sql, design-patterns, database-design

Nearly every project have search panel and custom filters in my company. It is hard to create when project has too much filter.

Is there any good design pattern for creating custom sql queries for using with filters?

I always write something like this:

```
commandText = "SELECT * FROM XXX "

innerJoinCommand = ""
whereCommand = ""

if (??.length > 0)
  whereCommand += "AND ??? "

if (??.Count > 0)
  innerJoinCommand += "??? "

//...

if (innerJoinCommand.length > 0)
  commandText += innerJoinCommand

if (whereCommand.length > 0)
  commandText += "WHERE " + whereCommand
```

Comment: "Design pattern"?  You keep using this term.  I do not think it means what you think it means.  : D  Sorry, had to.

Comment: so what do you prefer instead of "design pattern"?

Comment: I was joking.  Within the object-oriented world, the term "design pattern" has evolved into something that fits, somewhat ironically, into a subset of coding archetypes.  The big patterns don't really cover database interaction, which is why I said that.

Comment: Design patterns are not limited to object-oriented world. Any domain can have it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sort of thing is frequently done by using the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

If you want to support very complex queries, it might be a rather complex builder, and other patterns might come into play, but this is where I would start.

Comment: thanks... and i found it with your help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S

Comment: Here is one such implementation: https://github.com/mladenb/sql-query-builder

Answer (score 1):

I used the following design :

[Is it a oop good design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478087/is-it-a-oop-good-design)

The little trick is to put a "WHERE 1 = 1" so you don't have to handle if ti's a AND or a WHERE you have to add.

Comment: Small , but really useful trick. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do:
(srp is an object that contains all the possible parameters)

```
   string query = "select * from TABLE";

        if (srp != null)
        {
            query += " Where ";
            bool firstParameter = true;

            if (srp.ID!= 0)
            {
                if (!firstParameter)
                {
                    query += " and ";
                }
                query += " ID= " + srp.ID.ToString();
                firstParameter = false;
            }
        }
```

then you can replicate the inner if as much as you need.

Of course, this will only work with AND parameters, still didn't have to create a more complex logic to use or

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think it is confusing too and hard to implement... it should be easier than i think :)